# How to get previous record from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
 col1   | col2 | col3 |  col4 |
------------------------------------
  a    |  1   |   1  |   2    |
  b    |  2   |   2  |   6    |
  a    |  3   |   3  |   12   |
```

col4 = col2+col3+prev record col4

I can not solve the problem using mysql, its so hard for me

So can anyone help me?

Comment: I think we need more information about what your application is being used for to give the best answer. If you data is generated in order you may be better off pre-calculating `col5` rather than attempting to calculate it by running a query.

Comment: That would depend on the table structure and how the rows are related. Previous and next are dependent on the sort order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a variable for calculating *col4 = col2+col3+prev record col4*:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
       @prev := col2+col3+@prev as col4
from   t,
       (select @prev := 0) init
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df76c/2)

Note that to extend this you'd better define a sort order, as the above query could follow another order than you expect, depending on indexes the engine chooses to use (or not).

So for example, if *col2* would define the sort order, add `ORDER BY col2`

Comment: Yea, right. I am using MySQL. This would be perfect for accounting kinda purposes. You see, the cumulative model? :D I didn't know that I can do this way. This is awesome.

Comment: But won't this fail for the first row?

Comment: No, because the MySql engine first "evaluates" the `from` clause where *@prev* is given value 0. Only after that the engine will start fetching rows and evaluating what is in the `select` list.

Comment: Ah... That's nice. Thanks for the clarification. :D

Comment: "as the above query will follow the insertion order" - See how things may change without touching data in this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2649d2/1). So doing stuff like this without (distinct) `order by` is always a risk.

Comment: I have tried searching for previously and most complicated and This script is very simple and thank you

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, maybe I misunderstood your demo, but isn't that still keeping the insertion order?

Comment: The insertion order is the same. But the selection order changed because of the new index.

Comment: This is why scouring the likes of [this doc](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/) is important when using variables and assuming the output will always follow a quick test in production.

Comment: These can be a total pain @PraveenKumar often requiring 10 to 20 minutes to write. The importance of that article and seemingly, trivially, running stuff thru a function like coalesce or greatest(0,n) when n is always greater than 0, is to force a deliberate evaluation

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, maybe I miss something, but I see the same selection order as the insertion order in your demo.

Comment: @trincot, you need to uncomment the `alter table ..` line in the DDL/DML part: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed49c/1

Comment: @Drew - And you never know when the next version will optimize  away stuff like `IF(@a := @a+1, 1, 1)`. [This is another example](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/) of how optimizations can break code that uses "undocumented features".

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, ah, yes, I see what you did. I will update my answer accordingly.